# I've got two functions that differ only by some condition. Can it be unified?

Tags: c#, dry

So I have these two methods:

```
    public static string Figure2D()
    {
        dynamic shapeValue;
        do
        {
            shapeValue = Presentation.Present();
        }
        while (shapeValue.Is3D);
        return shapeValue.ToString("R");
    }

    public static string Figure3D()
    {
        dynamic shapeValue;
        do
        {
            shapeValue = Presentation.Present();
        }
        while (!shapeValue.Is3D);
        return shapeValue.ToString("R");
    }
```

The only difference between them is the while-condition. How can I merge these two into one function? Passing parameter values is probably necessary & acceptable, but I do like to keep it short. Any ideas?

Comment: @stuartd there's a `!` in one

Comment: @stuartd One is negated, the other isn't.

Comment: small text wins again, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about

```
public static string Figure(Predicate<dynamic> p)
    {
        dynamic shapeValue;
        do
        {
            shapeValue = Presentation.Present();
        }
        while (p(shapeValue));
        return shapeValue.ToString("R");
    }
```

Comment: I'd suggest `Func<dynamic, bool>` instead of `Predicate` so it can be used simply as `Figure(thing => !thing.Is3D)`

Comment: Hmm, what is Predicate, and how would I pass the condition? (sorry, kinda new to C#)

Comment: @Jesper: it's a delegate that returns a bool (as opposed to Func which returns anything you specify). Essentially, Predicate === Func<..., bool>.. For more info, check MSDN or intellisense in VS.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl sadly dynamic cannot be used in a lambda

Comment: @pm100: `Func<dynamic, bool> f = x => x.Length < 10;
Console.WriteLine(f("Hello, World!"));
Console.WriteLine(f("Hello"));` tested on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_csharp_online.php --- works, so **dynamic** can be used in lambdas. What did you mean?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl but what is the advantage of using `Func<dynamic,bool>` over `Predicate<dynamic>` here? `Predicate` can also be called simply using `Figure(p => p.Is3D)`

Comment: there are lambda / dynamic rules, maybe you cant define dynamics in lambdas, maybe it depends on c# version? I was bitten by this a few days ago on vs2015

Comment: @pm100: re: Func-vs-Predicate: no advantage. They are identical. I just noticed bare `Predicate` in the original text, so I suggested using a dynamically-typed version. I wrote `Func` just because I'm more used to it. Since it's identical - one less class name to remember. Stick to what you like more. My point was just that's X<dynamic,..> instead of just plain X.